# Excel not recognising a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

for some reason my excel drops error when multyipling on if statemtn

for example

```
=IF(A1>B1;A1*5;A1)
```

I cant do nothing, if Id skip it as 5x5 for exmaple, than it works perfect, though If I use an cell for a multiply, it drops me Value error.

I examined it and calculation steps are:

```
=IF(TRUE;"20.00"*5;A2), the 20.00 is what is A2 cell. 
=IF(TRUE;#VALUE!;A2)
```

So I am stuck and broken...

Comment: Try the formula as `=IF(A1>B1;NUMBERVALUE(A1)*5;A1)`

Comment: Doesnt work, drops me a Name error. as its not recognising the statement. :/

Comment: Why does your formula have semicolons instead of commas? Can you confirm you're using Excel 2010? What locality?

Comment: Try =IF(A1>B1;VALUE(A1)*5;A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange. When multiplying a string that looks like a number, Excel normally automatically converts the string to a number. Try this to force conversion:

```
=IF(A1>B1;VALUE(A1)*5;A1)
```

If that still results in an error, then Excel can't recognize "20.00" as a number. Does your locality use a comma instead of a fullstop for the decimal places? If so, try putting 20,00 in A1.

Also, try checking your locality settings. From the Start menu, search for Locality or Language, then choose to change your Date, Time or Number Formats. Click Additional settings and check what your Decimal Symbol is. You need to use this decimal symbol in Excel for it to correctly recognize numbers.

[image: System Number Formats]

Comment: ughh, Thanks a lot, stupid of me, forgot that we use commas instead of dots in numbers, why it cant be international >.> allright well thanks alot! :)

Answer (score -1):

Please use this formula,

```
=IF(A1>B1,PRODUCT(A1,5),A1)
```

Comment: Instead of doing all these you could just use the formula that i suggested

Comment: Your formula wouldn't have worked either because it was a data issue. The number was entered into A1 using the wrong symbol for the decimal, meaning it wasn't a number at all. Trying to multiple it by 5 had the same effect as trying to multiply "20!00" by 5 or the string "abc" by 5 - it's not possible. A1 just needed to have the number correctly entered as 20,00 to match the locality settings. This then meant it was a number.